# Syntastic: Show warnings in the gutter, but not in the location list

Tags: vim, syntastic

In the Syntastic plugin for VIM, is it possible for a Syntastic checker to report all errors and warnings in the gutter **but** only show errors (not warnings) in the location list?

I'd like to use VIM and Syntastic more like an IDE with passive strict warnings, so the location list only "pops" up into view when a compile error happens, while a more strict style issue is only noted in the gutter.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on the github repo for the Syntastic project and got the following response:

> No. There is a single list of messages, and several notification mechanisms using it. The gutter signs and the location list are two such mechanisms. Letting them go out of synch with each other would be a bad idea for many reasons, sorry.

The issue was then closed. So, unfortunately, it doesn't look like this is possible nor is it a planned feature to be implemented. :/